# How to rearrange mail merge documents in ms-word?

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

Requirement:
I have an excel file, which connects to Mail merge in word, which I already did.
Suppose there seems to be total 500 records in that excel, and have a field serial number, which seems to be unique from 1 to 500.  I need to list the details of the 1st record in top of the 1st A4 page and 251st record in bottom of the 1st A4 page, and 2nd record in top of the 2nd A4 page and 252nd record in bottom of the 2nd A4 page and so on.. and in 250th page,  250th record in top and 500th record in bottom of that page..

My Requirement is, when I cut this A4 size to 2 parts, the page needs to be sort in the serial number order.  Hope you understand my requirement.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You could ask on Super User or Microsoft Word Answers  ----
You are creating the document be the complete merge and then cutting the paper? Why not simply merge to A5 page size?

Comment: In Excel, add a 'helper' column with odd numbers 1, 3, 5, etc. down to row 250 and even numbers 2, 4 6, etc. from 251 to 500. In Word, use a label merge - with two labels per page - and use the mailmerge Edit Recipient List>Sort function to sort the data according to the Excel helper column.